# Always gets permission denied after I pull to our server

Tags: server, permissions, webapps

can I ask some help please. I'am deploying our webapp Laravel framework to our new server

my problem everytime I git pull from our new server. when I visit our webapp it will shows permission denied then I need to run again this command so that our webapp will up again.

```
sudo find /var/www/myapp-type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/myapp -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

By the way I don't know the www-data I just followed the tutorial https://linuxhint.com/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel/

sudo chown -R my-ssh-user:www-data /path/to/my/laravel-directory

Here is my server Ubuntu 20.4 focal

the shaded red is the username that I use to sshing in our server.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have POSIX ACL enabled on this filesystem, you can use it to give access for user www-data:

```
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX,d:u:www-data:rwX /var/www/xxxxx
```

The default entry will give access to files and directories created later.

Comment: what does the u stands for and the capital X ?

Comment: I installed the acl so that I can run your command provided

Comment: I think it works :)

Comment: The "u" stands for "user", and means that this acl entry is for user (there are also entries for group, mask, and others). From manual: "The character X stands for the execute permission if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user."